# Condition Action Statement - Feed Forward Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, decision-theory

I am trying to produce Decision Tree from Feed Forward Neural Network .

The input to the feed forward neural network is **Condition Action Statement**
for example, if airthrusthold > 90 , power up the engine else rotate shaft 5 degree wide

Above statement is the input to the FFNN . How do i feed the statement ? 
Either converting into word2vec ? (or) there is any other format to do ?

And i need to produce **decision tree** from the **outcome** of neural network

Can we do this using reinforcement learning using Markov Decision Process?

Thanks!